# Android - How to add multiple arrays to listview

Tags: android

I've put data from my database into four arrays but I want to bind it to my listview.
Unsure how to bind them to the listview with multiple arrays though.

My listview is four columns, so something like this (I'm aware this is wrong);

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.myactivity_four_column, meal[i], calories[i], fat[i], protein[i]);
```

Comment: create an object containing all of them and use the list of this object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define an `ArrayList` and pass it to the `ArrayAdapter`, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {meal[i], calories[i], fat[i], protein[i]}));
```

Then bind with `myList`

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.myactivity_four_column, myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object in place of four Arrays.

You can make Entity class (which has getter and setters) for it.. and then You can override the toString() method and return any variable of entity

and then u can make array adapter of that object and print the specific values. If you want to print all four values then u can return the string  which contains all four value by appending to one another and return it to toString() method..
like,

```
List<Object> objectList=getListFromDatabase();

 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.myactivity_four_column,objectList);
```

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);